absolutely positioned element goes out of screen
I have a paragraph which has certain words that have a description (in glossary table), so in each word that exists in the glossary there should be a plus sign, when i click it, it should show the description in a box over the text. each word that has a description is wrapped in glossary_container(positioned relative) class, and each description has a class glossary_description positioned absolute).
everything is working fine until the word is at the end of the line, the description goes out of container and ruins the style.
I would like a way to solve this, maybe the box can go to left instead of right if the content is too big, or maybe there is a way to keep the element within the width of the paragraph.


.glossary_description {
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.glossary_container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
<p style="
width: 765.328px;
">Imprisoned human rights defender Khalid al-Omair joined Waleed Abu Al-Khair on protest protest <span class="glossary_container"><span>hunger</span> <span class="plus-sign" data-index="2" data-title="Loremipsumdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum" style="cursor:pointer">-</span><span class="glossary_description">Loremipsumdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span></span>strike confirmed in protest of solitary strike<, abuse, and other forms of torture. By February 11th, both ended their strike.
<br>[INTERVIEW TO CUT: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78408304/edit"</a> Change Article to Audio
<br>Cut out: 01:29-1:46, 02:44-3:06</p>



edit**
*I added the actual html so you can see my problem
*class name is glossary_description no back slash
I added the image to further explain the problem here
enter image description here

Made your code into an executable snippet, but it looks like it is missing something. Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Not exactly a new issue though, did you try and research this? F.e. Prevent CSS tooltip from going out of page/window or How to ensure a tooltip stays within the browser visible area? are already dealing with pretty much the same problem.

Having tried to run your code it doesn't reproduce the problem, did you check to make sure that it's accurate? I imagine that part of the problem is the "" character in the "glossary\_description" class attribute but I'm afraid that's for you to work out, If your code isn't accurate then we can only guess what the problem, and solution, might be (which is of no real use to anyone, you, us, or future visitors with a similar sounding problem).

i made a few edits to my questions, please see it and try to help
